# Copy column B if column E or F is empty or comes with value 0

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file, and I want to use a bash with command awk or anything else to modify this file.

For example, I want to copy column B if column E or F comes empty or with the value of 0

```
AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE, FFFF
11    12    13    14    15    0
```

output:

```
AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE, FFFF
11    12    13    14    15    12
```

How can I do that?

UPDATE:
I run cat user.csv and shows this

```
740.58,0,740.58,0,740.58
2452.84,0,2452.84,0,2452.84
898.23,0,898.23,0,898.23
227.57,0,227.57,0,227.57
735.02,0,735.02,0,735.02
640.5,0,640.5,0,640.5
469.31,0,469.31,0,469.31
3744.25,0,3744.25,0,3744.25
462.15,0,462.15,0,462.15
198.79,0,198.79,0,198.79
437.58,0,437.58,0,437.58
515.44,0,515.44,0,515.44
```

and this is how it looks on LibreOffice

[image]

So what I want to do is replace the info of column C to column B, if all the info on column B has 0's if is not 0's don't change anything, I explained myself?

sorry for my English is not that good :c

UPDATE:
If statement something like this:

if [[ $2 == 0 ]]; then
echo "copy column 3 to 2"
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == 0 { $2 = $3 }; 1' user.csv > user1.csv
else
if [[ $4 == 0 ]]; then
echo "copy column 5 to 4"
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $4 == 0 { $4 = $5 }; 1' user.csv > user1.csv
fi
fi

Comment: That doesn't look like a csv file: where are the commas? Are the fields tab-separated, or is it some number of spaces?

Comment: What is the delimiter you use in your CSV data? Are the columns always in the shown order?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, the fields are tab-separated, This is just an example of how it looks if I open the file on LibreOffice

Comment: @Kusalananda The columns are always in order, I just want to copy the info of column B if the column F is empty

Comment: Rather than giving us a feel for what the data looks in LibreOffice, it would be better if you could include the actual data in the question, the way it looks if you ran `cat` on it in the terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda I make an update on the question, can you check pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == 0 { $2 = $3 }; 1' user.csv
740.58,740.58,740.58,0,740.58
2452.84,2452.84,2452.84,0,2452.84
898.23,898.23,898.23,0,898.23
227.57,227.57,227.57,0,227.57
735.02,735.02,735.02,0,735.02
640.5,640.5,640.5,0,640.5
469.31,469.31,469.31,0,469.31
3744.25,3744.25,3744.25,0,3744.25
462.15,462.15,462.15,0,462.15
198.79,198.79,198.79,0,198.79
437.58,437.58,437.58,0,437.58
515.44,515.44,515.44,0,515.44
```

This uses `awk` to set the second field (column) of each record (line) to the value of the third field, if the numeric value of the second field is zero.

The `BEGIN` block just sets the output field delimiter to whatever the input field delimiter is (it's a comma, set on the command line with `-F`).

The trailing `1` is the same as `{ print }`, which causes each record to be printed unconditionally.

---

Regarding your update to the question:  If you want to copy column 3 to column 2 if column 2 is zero (as above), and at the same time copy column 5 to column 4 if column 4 is zero, the above code could easily be extended like so:

```bsh
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    $2 == 0 { $2 = $3 }
    $4 == 0 { $4 = $5 }; 1' user.csv
```

Comment: It works, that's what I wanted to do, thanks a lot!

Comment: And how you can put this $ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == 0 { $2 = $3 }; 1' user.csv
in a if statement, something like this:

if [[ $2 == 0 ]]; then
 echo "copy column 3 to column 2"
 awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == 0 { $2 = $3 }; 1' user.csv > user1.csv
else
 if [[ $4 == 0 ]]; then
 echo "copy column 5 to column 4"
 awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $4 == 0 { $4 = $5 }; 1' user.csv > user1.csv
 fi
fi

Comment: @javila See updated answer.

Comment: Nice one, that works for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
gawk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
  !$5 {$5 = $2}
  !$6 {$6 = $2}
  1
' input.tsv
```

If the output looks right, re-execute with `gawk -i inplace '...' input.tsv`

Comment: Thanks, Glenn, but I make an update on the question, can you check pls